# Is requesting for brief content good?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when I ask questions, I request for brief explanation like:

> please explain in brief

So that, I will not get any answers which are better to be as comments. Is this good to say so?

Example:

- [How could Valmiki wrote Ramayana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/757/93)
- [What is the story of Kalki (tenth avatar of God Vishnu)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/579/93)

Please give your opinions.

Comment: You do realize not every question can be answered in brief, and some questions can only be answered in brief... don't you?

Comment: @AwalGarg if I do realize I will not ask for brief explanation. Here I am talking about the posts which has brief explanation. example is [your comment](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/757/how-could-valmiki-wrote-ramayana#comment1573_757) :P

Comment: Well, then ok, I don't see any harm in adding this innocent like to your questions. If someone feels it is inappropriate, he can always suggest an edit, and you can always rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say **Depends**

Now for example, if a user is asking for a story, one cannot write his own things to make a brief out of it, but as far as the question goes *Is requesting for brief content good?* so the answer is **YES**, it is good, more brief the answer is the clear understanding a user will get.

If you provide excessively long answers, write a short interesting summary of the answer at the beginning, users who find the summary interesting will read the brief answer.

Note for users who copy paste the answers, please write answers on your own, if you still copy, than make sure you copy only the relevant part and not an entire article from a foreign website.

**BUT**

Don't ask **questions** which are too broad, like,

- *What is Hinduism*
- *Everything about Lord Shiva*

are some examples which if a user asks will be closed as off-topic as answers will be extensively broad.

---

And last but not the least, don't ask for brief, let the user answer the way he wants to, if you need a brief, comment on the first answer you get like

*Can you explain me in brief*

Comment: "let the user answer the way he wants to" Agreed. However, in my opinion it is always appropriate to request a supplementary TL;DR.